# Android WindowManager Unable to transfer touch focus

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, android-windowmanager

Does anyone ever experienced with this error

```
1535-2103/system_process E/WindowManager: Unable to transfer touch focus
```

What i tried to do is trigger/delegate `LongClick` event from `PopupWindow` to underlying view to `startDrag()`

Code in underlying view(view that would be dragged)

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (!isDragAllowed()) {
            return false;
        }

        startDrag(v);

        dragAllowed = false;

        return false;
    }
```

[UI layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUWQY.png)

But above error always shown when `startDrag()` get called and `startDrag()` itself always return `false`

I know that inside `startDrag()` method that is a process `performDrag()` that cause the result was `false`

```
    public final boolean startDrag(ClipData data, DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder,
                Object myLocalState, int flags) {

            ...

                    //THIS ALWAYS RETURN FALSE
                    okay = mAttachInfo.mSession.performDrag(mAttachInfo.mWindow, token,
                            shadowSize.x, shadowSize.y,
                            shadowTouchPoint.x, shadowTouchPoint.y, data);
                    if (ViewDebug.DEBUG_DRAG) Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "performDrag returned " + okay);

                    // Off and running!  Release our local surface instance; the drag
                    // shadow surface is now managed by the system process.
                    surface.release();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Unable to initiate drag", e);
                surface.destroy();
            }

            return okay;
        }
```

But unfortunately i cant dive more on that since that method is member of `IWindowSession` which i dont know where the class is

Comment: I get the same error sometimes. I have a custom view (that extend Button) that I drag on a relative layout. Sometimes, and without an obvious reason, when I drag I get this error. I noticed that it happens when I make fast dragging moves. I can't find the reason for the problem since I cannot reproduce the error on purpose. It just happens sometimes. In case you still have the problem, maybe this could help you (I don't know what to do):https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0721861d6111a8a03eb0d4aad14b7a90fd83cab6/services/java/com/android/server/WindowManagerService.java